# HTML Table Code To Datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I have HTML Table code in my VB.NET apps. I want to show the table through DataGridView. I'd tried using for next but i'm not quite understand about it. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: If you only need to show it you can use a Webbrowser instead of a DataGridView

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest working with HTML Agility Pack if a WebBrowser is not suitable for this. Here is a very simple example.

For this demonstration I created a resource under project properties, resources add new text file and named it MyHtml, dumped the following into it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1" bordercolor="#808080" cellpadding="2">
        <tr>
            <th>One</th>
            <th>Two</th>
            <th>Three</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 A</td>
            <td>Row 1 B</td>
            <td>Row 1 C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 A</td>
            <td>Row 2 B</td>
            <td>Row 2 C</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Add a class to the project

```
Public Class Class1
    Public Function Demo1() As DataTable
        Dim Document As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()

        Document.LoadHtml(My.Resources.MyHtml)
        Dim table As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode =
            Document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@border='1']")

        Dim dt As New DataTable()

        Dim rows = table.SelectNodes("tr")

        For row As Integer = 0 To rows.Count - 1
            'if row = then these are headers
            If row = 0 Then

                Dim cols = rows(row).SelectNodes("th")

                dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(cols(0).InnerText.ToString()))
                dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(cols(1).InnerText.ToString()))
                dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(cols(2).InnerText.ToString()))

            Else
                Dim cols = rows(row).SelectNodes("td")

                Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()

                dr(0) = cols(0).InnerText.ToString()
                dr(1) = cols(1).InnerText.ToString()
                dr(2) = cols(2).InnerText.ToString()

                dt.Rows.Add(dr)

            End If
        Next

        Return dt

    End Function
End Class
```

In the form

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim c1 As New Class1
        dataGridView1.DataSource = c1.Demo1
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]